# Get frequency wav audio using FFT and Complex class

Tags: android, audio, fft, frequency

It's been asked a lot, but I still stuck about implement FFT class on Android
I need to process my audio data using FFT...

I already read the almost same question here [How can I get frequency data from PCM using FFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604011/how-can-i-get-frequency-data-from-pcm-using-fft)
and here [How to get frequency from fft result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674877/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result)
and more questions but still find no answer even after I tried the answers given...

FFT Class I'm using: 
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/97data/FFT.java

The complex class to go with it: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/Complex.java.html

Here's my code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Latihan extends Activity{
        private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
        private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV = ".wav";
        private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";
        private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE = "record_temp.raw";
        private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
        private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
        private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
        short[] audioData;

        private AudioRecord recorder = null;
        private int bufferSize = 0;
        private Thread recordingThread = null;
        private boolean isRecording = false;
        Complex[] fftTempArray;
        Complex[] fftArray;
        int[] bufferData;
        int bytesRecorded;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.p1);

        setButtonHandlers();
        enableButtons(false);

        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize
                (RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING)*3;

        audioData = new short [bufferSize]; //short array that pcm data is put into.

        }


    private void setButtonHandlers() {
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btStart)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btStop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
        }


        private void enableButton(int id,boolean isEnable){
                ((Button)findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
        }

        private void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
                enableButton(R.id.btStart,!isRecording);
                enableButton(R.id.btStop,isRecording);
        }

        private String getFilename(){
                String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
                File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

                if(!file.exists()){
                        file.mkdirs();
                }

                return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV);
        }


        public void convert(){



        }

        public void calculate(){
            Complex[] fftTempArray = new Complex[bufferSize];
            for (int i=0; i<bufferSize; i++)
            {
                fftTempArray[i] = new Complex(audioData[i], 0);
            }
            Complex[] fftArray = FFT.fft(fftTempArray);

            double[] micBufferData = new double[bufferSize];
            final int bytesPerSample = 2; 
            final double amplification = 100.0; 
            for (int index = 0, floatIndex = 0; index < bytesRecorded - bytesPerSample + 1; index += bytesPerSample, floatIndex++) {
                double sample = 0;
                for (int b = 0; b < bytesPerSample; b++) {
                    int v = bufferData[index + b];
                    if (b < bytesPerSample - 1 || bytesPerSample == 1) {
                        v &= 0xFF;
                    }
                    sample += v << (b * 8);
                }
                double sample32 = amplification * (sample / 32768.0);
                micBufferData[floatIndex] = sample32;
            }


     }


        private String getTempFilename(){
                String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
                File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

                if(!file.exists()){
                        file.mkdirs();
                }

                File tempFile = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);

                if(tempFile.exists())
                        tempFile.delete();

                return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
        }

        private void startRecording(){
            recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                                                RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

                recorder.startRecording();

                isRecording = true;

                recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                                writeAudioDataToFile();
                        }
                },"AudioRecorder Thread");

                recordingThread.start();
        }

        private void writeAudioDataToFile(){
                byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
                String filename = getTempFilename();
                FileOutputStream os = null;

                try {
                        os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

                int read = 0;

                if(null != os){
                        while(isRecording){
                                read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

                                if(AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read){
                                        try {
                                                os.write(data);
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                }
                        }

                        try {
                                os.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
        }

        private void stopRecording(){
                if(null != recorder){
                        isRecording = false;

                        recorder.stop();
                        recorder.release();

                        recorder = null;
                        recordingThread = null;
                }

                copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(),getFilename());
               // deleteTempFile();
        }

        private void deleteTempFile() {
                File file = new File(getTempFilename());
                file.delete();
        }

        private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename,String outFilename){
                FileInputStream in = null;
                FileOutputStream out = null;
                long totalAudioLen = 0;
                long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
                long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
                int channels = 2;
                long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels/8;

                byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

                try {
                        in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
                        out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
                        totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
                        totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

                        AppLog.logString("File size: " + totalDataLen);

                        WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                                        longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

                        while(in.read(data) != -1){
                                out.write(data);
                        }

                        in.close();
                        out.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        private void WriteWaveFileHeader(
                        FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
                        long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels,
                        long byteRate) throws IOException {
            //another code    

        }

        private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     switch(v.getId()){
                              case R.id.btStart:{
                                        AppLog.logString("Start Recording");
                                        enableButtons(true);
                                        startRecording();
                                        break;
                                }
                                case R.id.btStop:{
                                    AppLog.logString("Stop Recording");
                                        enableButtons(false);
                                        stopRecording();
                                        calculate();
                                        break;

                                }
                        }
                }
        }; 
}
```

I assume the audioData array contains the raw audio data,but my code catch the exception and return "N is not a power of 2"

Is it anything wrong with my code ??
How do I pass it to FFT.java class and get the fftResult ??

Or is there an other way to convert time domain data to frequency data that more easier ?

It's been a few months since I get stuck with this... My project is too compare 2 audio of *.wav files,
Any help would be appreciated... :)

Comment: For those of you with a similar error of "N is not a power of 2", it means the FFT algorithm you're using expects an array with a size 2^n, where 'n' is an integer greater than 0. The FFT algorithm works most efficiently on algorithms of these sizes, by using the Cooley-Tukey FFT transform, which operates using 2 radices.


One solution is to search for an FFT algorithm which also incorporates the Bluestein transform, which can be used for arrays of arbitrary lengths. One such FFT is found here at : https://www.nayuki.io/page/free-small-fft-in-multiple-languages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I already found the answer... :)

I create method to calculate array value from audio...

```
public double[] calculateFFT(byte[] signal)
    {           
        final int mNumberOfFFTPoints =1024;
        double mMaxFFTSample;

        double temp;
        Complex[] y;
        Complex[] complexSignal = new Complex[mNumberOfFFTPoints];
        double[] absSignal = new double[mNumberOfFFTPoints/2];

        for(int i = 0; i < mNumberOfFFTPoints; i++){
            temp = (double)((signal[2*i] & 0xFF) | (signal[2*i+1] << 8)) / 32768.0F;
            complexSignal[i] = new Complex(temp,0.0);
        }

        y = FFT.fft(complexSignal); // --> Here I use FFT class

        mMaxFFTSample = 0.0;
        mPeakPos = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < (mNumberOfFFTPoints/2); i++)
        {
             absSignal[i] = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y[i].re(), 2) + Math.pow(y[i].im(), 2));
             if(absSignal[i] > mMaxFFTSample)
             {
                 mMaxFFTSample = absSignal[i];
                 mPeakPos = i;
             } 
        }

        return absSignal;

    }
```

Then I called it in class Write Audio..

```
private void writeAudioDataToFile(){

        byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
        String filename = getTempFilename();
       FileOutputStream os = null;

        try {
                os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int read = 0;                
        if(null != os){
                while(isRecording){
                        read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);
                        if(read > 0){
                            absNormalizedSignal = calculateFFT(data); // --> HERE ^__^
                        }

                        if(AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read){
                                try {
                                        os.write(data);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                        }
                }

                try {
                        os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: what is "complex"?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your immediate problem is "N is not a power of 2." In this case, N is probably referring to the size of the data you are putting into your FFT. Most FFT algorithms only work on blocks of data that have a size that is a power of 2.

Are you trying to put the entire file into an FFT at once? If so, you may need to read more background material to understand what you are doing. Maybe start here: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html

Comment: Thanks alot for ur response... :)
Ohh yes... I already read that post before...
and another post from that blog too...
That's ur blog right ?? :)

But I still don't fully understand about cut the data with Windowing then do the FFT part...

Can u give me sample maybe ??
I'm really really new in this audio data processing world...
I got the theory, but I can't really understand the implementation maybe unless I see sample code... :(

Comment: Yes, that's my blog. The complete code for that sample is linked from that post. https://github.com/bejayoharen/guitartuner

Comment: Hi, @Silviya. I also need to fetch two specified frequencies from a wave file. I also checked few posts, blogs and even StackOverflow's question, but I was not able to find any relevant answer. I am not using android. I just want it in Java. I am really new in audio, therefore, I have no experience. Can you kindly help me out with that? I'll really appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: @VibhavChaddha Hi, the FFT and complex class I'm using is based on java as well as android. You can track back my questions in stackoverflow, since each question has already been answered. 
And this blog http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/07/frequency-detection-using-fft-aka-pitch.html from BjornRoche is very helpful. 
Please contact me via email for further question.

Comment: There's an FFT-based guitar tuner written in java in this book: https://www.amazon.com/Digital-Audio-Java-Craig-Lindley/dp/0130876763 It's a little outdated and has some issues, but the code is there.