# How to calculate frequency level from audio recorder mic input data

Tags: android, audio, fft, audio-recording, arduino-ultra-sonic

I am doing sound analyzer application in android.I can generate 18 khz to 20 khz ultrasonic sound using AudioTrack Api.i can record audio using AudioRecord Api.But i don't know how to calculate frequency form mic input data.i saw multiple question [How to get frequency from fft result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674877/how-to-get-frequency-from-fft-result) and [Get frequency wav audio using FFT and Complex class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429407/get-frequency-wav-audio-using-fft-and-complex-class.But) it not giving proper frequency.Please help me .sorry for my communication.

This is my frequency calculation code

```
int bufferSizeInBytes = 1024; 
short[] buffer = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];
class Recording extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {

                bufferReadResult = audioInput.read(buffer, 0, bufferSizeInBytes); // record data from mic into buffer                    

                if(bufferReadResult > 0){
                   calculate();
                }              
        }
    }   


public void calculate() {
    DoubleFFT_1D fft1d = new DoubleFFT_1D(bufferSizeInBytes);//using JTransforms lib
    double[] fftBuffer = new double[bufferSizeInBytes * 2];
    double[] magnitude = new double[bufferSizeInBytes / 2];

    // copy real input data to complex FFT buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < bufferSizeInBytes - 1; ++i) {
        fftBuffer[2 * i] = buffer[i];
        fftBuffer[2 * i + 1] = 0;
    }
    //perform  FFT on fft[] buffer
    fft1d.realForward(fftBuffer);

    // calculate power spectrum (magnitude) values from fft[]
    for (int i = 0; i < (bufferSizeInBytes / 2) - 1; ++i) {

        double real = fftBuffer[2 * i];
        double imaginary = fftBuffer[2 * i + 1];
        magnitude[i] = Math.sqrt(real * real + imaginary * imaginary);

    }

    // find largest peak in power spectrum
    double max_magnitude = magnitude[0];
    int max_index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < magnitude.length; ++i) {
        if (magnitude[i] > max_magnitude) {
            max_magnitude = (int) magnitude[i];
            max_index = i;
        }
    }
    double freq = max_index * 44100 / bufferSizeInBytes;
    Log.e("AudioBEacon", "" + freq);
}
```

}

This is my output.Please let me know where i did mistake.

```
02-10 12:33:04.450 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21662.0
02-10 12:33:04.451 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21317.0
02-10 12:33:04.453 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21791.0
02-10 12:33:04.471 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21748.0
02-10 12:33:04.472 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21533.0
02-10 12:33:04.474 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21834.0
02-10 12:33:04.491 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21533.0
02-10 12:33:04.493 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21705.0
02-10 12:33:04.511 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21533.0
02-10 12:33:04.512 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21447.0
02-10 12:33:04.513 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21490.0
02-10 12:33:04.531 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21576.0
02-10 12:33:04.551 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21619.0
02-10 12:33:04.591 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21877.0
02-10 12:33:04.613 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21576.0
02-10 12:33:04.633 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21920.0
02-10 12:33:04.653 17013-17063/com.org.sohamsaa.audiobeacontransmitter E/AudioBEacon: 21791.0
```

My frequency range is 18 khz to 20 khz.but i don't get my frequency.how to filter my frequency.thank you.

Comment: Remove the `(int)` cast here: `max_magnitude = (int) magnitude[i];` - there may be other problems but this is definitely wrong. Note also that most devices have very poor sensitivity at > 18 kHz - the microphone usually has a poor response above 15 kHz and the anti-aliassing filter may also reduce levels further.

Comment: @ Paul R Thanks for your reply and i remove (int).But it is not working and i generate 14 khz frequency but i'm not getting.This is my log result

E/AudioBEacon: 861.0
E/AudioBEacon: 21404.0
E/AudioBEacon: 21705.0
E/AudioBEacon: 21447.0
E/AudioBEacon: 215.0
E/AudioBEacon: 21705.0
E/AudioBEacon: 344.0
E/AudioBEacon: 473.0
E/AudioBEacon: 430.0

Comment: what is window function?and  how to do?

Comment: Try plotting your time domain waveform and spectrum to see if they look reasonable - that's usually a good way to narrow down the problem. For window functions you can just [search here on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Window+function+%5Bdsp%5D) and/or read the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function).

Answer (score 5):

See my sample project. :D [Github](https://github.com/lucns/Android-Audio-Sample).

This retrieve frequency with high precision and big velocity, based on a Spectrum Analyzer app developed by Google developers.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the answer.Just apply FFT instead of JTransforms lib in my code.This code is working for me.

```
int bufferSizeInBytes = 1024; 
short[] buffer = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];
class Recording extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while () {

            if (true) {                   
                int bufferReadResult = audioInput.read(buffer, 0, bufferSizeInBytes); // record data from mic into buffer
                if (bufferReadResult > 0) {
                    calculate();
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
public void calculate() {

    double[] magnitude = new double[bufferSizeInBytes / 2];

    //Create Complex array for use in FFT
    Complex[] fftTempArray = new Complex[bufferSizeInBytes];
    for (int i = 0; i < bufferSizeInBytes; i++) {
        fftTempArray[i] = new Complex(buffer[i], 0);
    }

    //Obtain array of FFT data
    final Complex[] fftArray = FFT.fft(fftTempArray);
    // calculate power spectrum (magnitude) values from fft[]
    for (int i = 0; i < (bufferSizeInBytes / 2) - 1; ++i) {

        double real = fftArray[i].re();
        double imaginary = fftArray[i].im();
        magnitude[i] = Math.sqrt(real * real + imaginary * imaginary);

    }

    // find largest peak in power spectrum
    double max_magnitude = magnitude[0];
    int max_index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < magnitude.length; ++i) {
        if (magnitude[i] > max_magnitude) {
            max_magnitude = (int) magnitude[i];
            max_index = i;
        }
    }
    double freq = 44100 * max_index / bufferSizeInBytes;//here will get frequency in hz like(17000,18000..etc)        

}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm for me! For anyone else interested in this, you can find the FFT implementation here https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/FFT.java.html and the implementation for the Complex numbers here https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/Complex.java.html.