# Android : How to Get the amplitude and Frequency of a sound in a .wav file at particular Second

Tags: android, arrays, loops, audio

I am working on an Android Project in which ,
Let's Say I have an audio file in .wav format

I want to create an array in which i want to set three fields :
1. Time (in Seconds or in Mili Seconds) of audio file.
2. Amplitude at that particular Second of audio file.
3. Frequency at that particular Second of audio file.

I am thinking that i can use "for OR while" loop to create the array by getting amplitude and frequency at each second and save add it to my array list.

But I don't know how to get the value of amplitude and freuency at that particular Second from my audio file.

I never worked with audios before, So I don't know , Is there any method to get these values.

I am thinking that as amplitude can be represented on graphs of amplitude and time, amplitude can be an integer or long ( I actually Don't Know ).

Is it possible ? If Yes than How can I achieve this.

Thank You In Advance :-)

Comment: here on SO questions should be answerable with a focused pinpoint reusable answer ... what you ask here takes months of research to really understand ... for starters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429407/get-frequency-wav-audio-using-fft-and-complex-class